# Why won't my container component receive result of Async Await properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is driving me a bit nuts.

Expected Behaviour:

I click a button > it fires checkLoginStatus > which returns true or false from firebase > boolean is stored in isLoggedIn > that is console.log'd out

Actual Results:
I click the button > it fires the function off > the console log comes through as undefined/false > then the user object is returned.

Question:
Why is my React container method `isUserAlreadyAuthenticated()` logging out before the `await` has completed?

**Context:**

I've got a set of 4 utility functions. Each of them focus on diff elements on the firebase/login lifecycle (sign up, login, log-out, hasUserAuthenticatedBefore...)

they are all async-await functions. So, for example: here's the login one - which works fine:-

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
    let defaultStatus = false;
    try {
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(res => {
                // if firebase fires back a user object, then login is true.
                if (res.user.email) {
                    defaultStatus = true;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Firebase | sign in error: ', error.message);
                defaultStatus = false;
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Login | error: ', err);
    }
    console.log('login status after logging in Try/Catch is: ', defaultStatus);
    return defaultStatus;
}
```

NOTE: when i call this function in my container, it gets the correct returned boolean response.

Now... if i look at the checkLoginStatus function. No variation or weird and wonderful re-writes can get it to behave in a similar fashion.

```
export const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
    let defaultStatus = false;
    try {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            // if user exists then defaultStatus = true;
            // if not exists then defaultStatus = false;
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('sign up user error: ', err);
    }
    console.log('default status after checking login status: ', defaultStatus);
    return defaultStatus;
}
```

Then in my container:-

```
isUserAlreadyAuthenticated = async () => {
    let isLoggedIn = await this.props.checkLoginStatus();
    console.log('is foo here? ===>', isLoggedIn); // undefined
}
```

Things I've tried:-

Changing the util function to a promise (this gets checkLoginStatus is not a function error)

removing async from isUserAlreadyAuthenticated; firing it off like a normal function (as the async part is managed in the util function itself). No joy.

changing onAuthStateChanged() api to a `.then()` style promise. no change.

I removed all Firebase code from `checkLoginStatus` & just made it return a string after a `setTimeout()` - and it was still **returning undefined before the user object had been retrieved**.

What am i not seeing here?

Comment: *"What am i not seeing here?"* What makes it work in the first case is the use of `await`. You are not using `await` in the second case. However, the way you mix `async/await` and `.then` callbacks is rather unusual. You should rather do `try { return Boolean((await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()).user.email); } catch(e) { return false; }`

Comment: I recommend to [read up more on `async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to get a better understanding about how it actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @FelixKling and @Think-Twice .

I did actually end up a) wrapping the util function in a Promise, *and* reading up on async await. Thought i understood that but there were some quirks i didnt.

The key seemed to be putting in a recursive element though.

util function:

```
export function checkLoginStatus() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            unsubscribe(); // <--- calls itself and resolves with a successful user object or null
            resolve(user);
        }, reject('api has failed'));
    });
}
```

This calls itself until the user response is either a successful user object OR returns null.

On the React side i then have an Async-Await function to wait on the promise:

```
   isUserAlreadyAuthenticated = async () => {

        try {
            let user = await this.props.checkLoginStatus();
            console.log('react side: ', user);
            if (user && user.email) {
                this.setState({
                    isLoggedIn: true, // <-- when true page navs to Homepage
                });
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('catch | api error: ', err);   
        }
    }
```

I hope thats helpful for others that are manoeuvring around the `onAuthStateChanged()` api. It isnt a promise, it's not thennable. it has to take a callback.